# Python np.convolve/SUMPRODUCT for many Arrays

Tags: python, excel, np

I need to implement this formula Excel in Python

```
SUMPRODUCT($C$10:D$10;$C$30:D$30;reverse($C$40:D$40);reverse($C$50:D$50))
```

I trying this with `np.convolve`, But this function accept only two array.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
c = np.array([7,8,9])
d = np.array([10,11,12])

sumproduct = np.sum(a*b*c*d)
```

You can reverse arrays using `np.flip(array,axis)`.